# Generic jsonObjectparsing using gson

Tags: kotlin, gson

Hi there im trying to make a generic client and trying to parse the json to a object.

```
gson?.fromJson(khttpResponse.jsonObject.toString(), 
UserInfo::class.java)
```

works.

```
val listType = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
gson?.fromJson(khttpResponse.jsonObject.toString(), listType)
```

Doesnt't work. So my question is there a workaround to to parse json in gson or do you guys use some other libary?

UserInfo:

```
open class UserInfo (
    val profileId: String,
    val code: String,
    val message: String,
    val path: String,
    val profile: Profile,
    val errorDetail: Any
)

data class Profile(
    val firstname: String,
    val lastname: String

)
```

Comment: What do your Json and `UserInfo` class look like?

Comment: @user2340612 added

Comment: Does your JSON's properties match exactly the fields of your `UserInfo`/`Profile` classes?

Comment: yes. the problem is that I want to use the generic.